# What are the most common ways to deploy rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I use Heroku to host and deploy a lot of little apps, in the past I remember ftp'ing and then Capistrano came around and made things a lot better.

Is Capistrano still the default deployment method or are there up and coming techniques or existing methods to deploy rails apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano is still at the state of the art, generally used with github.

Of course the easiest way to host your apps is Heroku if don't have your own server.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the other Heroku and Capistrano answers.

Outside of that, I'm particularly looking forward to seeing what VMWare's [CloudFoundry](http://cloudfoundry.com/) has in store for us. One step deploys (and upgrades) very similar to Heroku, and you can actually host your own clouds if you want to. It's still in beta, but looks pretty slick from what I've been following of it. Supports Ruby (Rails, Sinatra, et al), Node, Java, and others.